# "Like" condition instead of an "isin" in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a parameter dictionary as below -

```
paramDict = {
    "DataFilter": {
        "tableField": [{
            "table":"GL_LEDGERS",
            "field":"NAME"
        }],
        "value" : ["ABC."]
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a "like" instead of the "isin" condition so that the data gets filtered for "ABC" as well as "ABC." -

```
DataFilter = df['NAME'].isin(
    pd.Series(paramDict['DataFilter']['value']))
df = df[DataFilter]
```

Can you please help me with the same. I am using python 2.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `Series` is a string type.

If so, you can use `.contains`:

```
DataFilter = df['NAME'].str.contains('ABC')
```